# Derivation of Ward identity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, noethers-theorem, ward-identity

Can we derive Ward identity from Noether current of a Lagrangian density, under the assumption that path integral measure is invariant?

Suppose that $\delta\psi(x) = \frac{d\hat{\psi}(x, \epsilon)}{d\epsilon}\bigr|_{\epsilon = 0}$ is a smooth variation such that $\psi(x) = \hat{\psi}(x, 0)$. In fact,

$$\hat{\psi}(x, \epsilon) = \psi(x)+\epsilon\delta \psi(x)\tag{1}$$

Then,

$$\begin{align}
 \delta\mathcal{L} &= \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial\psi} - \partial_\mu\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_\mu\psi)}\right)\delta\psi + \partial_\mu J^\mu,\quad  J^\mu = \frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_\mu\psi)}\delta\psi.\tag{2}
\end{align}$$

For the action $\displaystyle S[\psi] = \int \mathcal{L}(\psi, \partial_{\mu}\psi)d^nx$, the variation of the path integral $$Z[\psi] = \int D[\psi]e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\psi]}\tag{3}$$

is

$$\delta Z[\psi] = \frac{d}{d\epsilon}\biggr|_{e = 0}\biggr(\int D[\hat{\psi}]e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\hat{\psi}]}\biggr) = \int \frac{d\mathcal{D}[\hat{\psi}]}{de}\biggr|_{\epsilon = 0}e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\hat{\psi}]} + \frac{i}{\hbar}\int \mathcal{D}[\hat{\psi}]\frac{dS[\hat{\psi}]}{de}\biggr|_{\epsilon = 0}e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\psi]}\tag{4}$$

Where

$$\frac{dS[\hat{\psi}]}{d\epsilon}\biggr|_{\epsilon = 0} = \int \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial\psi} - \partial_\mu\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_\mu\psi)}\right)\delta\psi + \partial_{\mu}\biggr(\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_\mu\psi)}\delta\psi\biggr)\biggr)d^nx\tag{5}$$

Under the assumption that Lagrangian is on-shell, this simplifies to

$$\frac{dS[\hat{\psi}]}{d\epsilon}\biggr|_{\epsilon = 0} = \int\partial_{\mu}\biggr(\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_\mu\psi)}\delta\psi\biggr)d^nx\tag{6}$$

From which we conclude that

$$\begin{align}\displaystyle\frac{i}{\hbar}\int \mathcal{D}[\hat{\psi}]\frac{dS[\hat{\psi}]}{d\epsilon}\biggr|_{\epsilon = 0}e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\psi]} &= \frac{i}{\hbar}\int \mathcal{D}[\hat{\psi}]\biggr(\int\partial_{\mu}\bigr(\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_\mu\psi)}\delta\psi\bigr)d^nx\biggr)e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\psi]}\\ &= \frac{i}{\hbar}\int \mathcal{D}[\hat{\psi}]\biggr(\int\partial_{\mu}J^{\mu}d^nx\biggr)e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\psi]}\end{align}\tag{7}$$

Thus,

$$\delta Z[\psi] = \int \delta\mathcal{D}[\psi]e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\psi]} + \frac{i}{\hbar}\int \mathcal{D}[\psi]\biggr(\int\partial_{\mu}J^{\mu}d^nx\biggr)e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\psi]}\tag{8}$$

However, I'm not sure whether this is the right way to derive Ward identity, and whether I have a clear interpretation of my derivations.

Comment: I think formula (6) is not valid in this context, since the term $\frac{dS[\psi]}{d \epsilon}_{\epsilon =0}$ is in the path integral in (4) and the path integral integrates over all field configurations, also the ones that are not solution of the lagrange equations, so it's not necessarily true that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \psi}-\partial _\mu \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial _\mu \psi)}=0$.

Answer (score 7):

For what it's worth the usual argument is as follows:

1. If the path integral measure $\delta_{\epsilon} \left({\cal D}\phi\right)=0$ has a local(=$x$-dependent) symmetry, one may derive the following
   [Schwinger-Dyson (SD) equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger%E2%80%93Dyson_equation)
   $$\langle \delta_{\epsilon}F[\phi]\rangle + \frac{i}{\hbar} \langle F[\phi]\delta_{\epsilon}S[\phi]\rangle~=~0,\tag{A}$$
   cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/460441/2451) related Phys.SE post.
2. If moreover the action $S[\phi]$ has the corresponding global [quasisymmetry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/11317/2451) $\delta_{\epsilon} S[\phi] = \int  \mathrm{d}^n x ~ J^{\mu}~  d_{\mu}\epsilon$, one gets the following [Ward-Takahashi identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward%E2%80%93Takahashi_identity)
   $$\langle \frac{\delta \delta_{\epsilon}F[\phi]}{\delta \epsilon(x)}\rangle ~=~ \frac{i}{\hbar} \langle F[\phi]d_{\mu}J^{\mu}(x)\rangle.\tag{B}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do but got confused along the way is the following:

Regardless of whether you have a symmetry or not the following equation is always true:$\newcommand{\D}{\mathrm{D}}\newcommand{\ex}[1]{\mathrm{e}^{#1}}$
$$ Z = \int \D{\phi}\ \ex{-S[\phi]} = \int \D{\phi'}\ \ex{-S[\phi']}.\tag{1}\label{1}$$
So far I've just relabeled my integration dummy variables.

Now take $\phi'(x) = \phi(x) + \epsilon(x)\, \delta\phi(x)$ and assume that it is a non-anomalous symmetry, i.e. both the action and the measure are invariant. Then what you get is (see e.g. page 19 of [David Tong's QFT notes](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html)):
$$ Z = \int \D{\phi}\ \ex{-S[\phi]}\left(1 - \int \mathrm{d}^d x\ J^\mu(x) \partial_\mu \epsilon(x)\right),$$
which using \eqref{1} gives
$$ \int \D{\phi}\ \ex{-S[\phi]}\left(\int \mathrm{d}^d x\ J^\mu(x) \partial_\mu \epsilon(x)\right) = 0,$$
which, since it's true for arbitrary $\epsilon(x)$, is the same as
$$\left<\partial_\mu J^\mu(x) \right> = 0.$$

You can repeat the same for correlation functions, i.e. change the dummy variable in the path integral expression for $\left<\mathcal{O}_1(x_1)\cdots\mathcal{O}_n(x_n)\right>$ and play the same game. Now you have to include the variations of the operators:
$$\mathcal{O}_i(x_i) \mapsto \mathcal{O}_i(x_i) + \epsilon(x_i)\, \delta\mathcal{O}_i(x_i),$$
finding, after the same steps:
$$ \left<\partial_\mu J^\mu(x)\ \mathcal{O}_1(x_1)\cdots\mathcal{O}_n(x_n)\right> = \sum_{i=1}^n \delta(x-x_i) \left<\mathcal{O}_1(x_1)\cdots\delta\mathcal{O}_i(x_i)\cdots\mathcal{O}_n(x_n)\right>.$$
This is a Ward identity.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, although I'm still curious (assuming that my math is flawless along the computations) whether what I derived in my question.

Comment: @Supergravity your math is not correct. For example all expressions containing a $\int\mathrm{D}\psi$ hitting *nothing* are big red flags.

Comment: Yes, that term was what I was particularly concerned about. However, are you suggesting that we cannot simply take $\frac{dS[\hat{\psi}]}{ds}\biggr|_{s = 0}$ out of the path integral?

Comment: @Supergravity yes, you cannot do that

Comment: @Supergravity you have defined $\psi(x)$ as $\hat\psi(x,0)$ so they're not independent. Anyways, all of these are comments to your computations and not suitable to be discussed under this answer.

Comment: Should I create a new question for asking about these computations?

Comment: @Supergravity no. Check-my-work questions are considered  off-topic on this site.

Comment: You should upvote and/or approve either of the existing answers if you found them useful and try on your own to see how to make your calculations commensurate with them

Comment: I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149005/discussion-between-dt-strl-and-supergravity).